# Electron store reference to new BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a github auth link in my app which triggers the 'new-window' listener'

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) => {
// how do i store a reference to the newly created window here
})
```

How do i store a refernce to this new window so i can later perform actions on the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead of letting electron make the window make the window yourself like what it says further down in the documentation.

Then you could store a reference to the window variable and do things with it like this:

```
var newWindow;

myBrowserWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => win.show())
  win.loadURL(url)
  event.newGuest = win
  newWindow      = win;
})

// Do something with the window.
newWindow.hide();
```

[Documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#event-new-window)

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that the link is triggered by the firebase SDK and opens a github auth page. Because the link is initially about:blank then redirects I don’t have access to the url when this is called

Comment: Ah ok, so what do you want to do to the window?

Comment: I ideally want to force the link to open outside of app in the users default browser is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can using `shell.openExternal('www.google.com')` this will open google in the users default browser. https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/shell/#shellopenexternalurl-options-callback

Comment: How can I do this without having access to the url in the new-window listener?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get the url, that's up to you to figure out

Comment: Wasnt sure if there was another event I could listen to that would return the right url even if a redirect takes place. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159091/discussion-between-mike-wood-and-samuel).

Comment: @Samuel If my answer was useful could you up-vote and accept?